# Best practices to execute faster a CasperJS script that scrapes thousands of pages

Tags: arrays, performance, time, casperjs, execution

I've written a CasperJS script that works very well except that it takes a (very very) long time to scrape pages.

In a nutshell, here's the pseudo code:

1. my functions to scrape the elements
2. my `casper.start()` to start the navigation and log in
3. `casper.then()` where I loop through an array and store my links
4. `casper.thenOpen()` to open each link and call my functions to scrap.

It works perfectly (and fast enough) for scraping a bunch of links. But when it comes to thousands (right now I'm running the script with an array of 100K links), the execution time is endless: the first 10K links have been scrapped in 3h54m10s and the following 10K in 2h18m27s.

I can explain a little bit the difference between the two 10K batches : the first includes the looping & storage of the array with the 100K links. From this point, the scripts only open pages to scrap them. However, I noticed the array was ready to go after roughly 30 minutes so it doesn't explain exactly the time gap.

I've placed my `casper.thenOpen()` in the for loop hoping that after each new link built and stored in the array, the scrapping will happen. Now, I'm sure I've failed this but will it change anything in terms of performance ?

That's the only lead I have in mind right now and I'd be very thankful if anyone is willing to share his/her best practices to reduce significantly the running time of the script's execution (shouldn't be hard!).

**EDIT #1**

Here's my code below:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');

// This array maintains a list of links to each HOL profile

// Example of a valid URL: https://myurl.com/list/74832
var root = 'https://myurl.com/list/';
var end = 0;
var limit = 100000;
var scrapedRows = [];

// Returns the selector element property if the selector exists but otherwise returns defaultValue

function querySelectorGet(selector, property, defaultValue) {
  var item = document.querySelector(selector);
  item =  item ? item[property] : defaultValue;
  return item;
}

// Scraping function
function scrapDetails(querySelectorGet) {

  var info1 = querySelectorGet("div.classA h1", 'innerHTML', 'N/A').trim()
  var info2 = querySelectorGet("a.classB span", 'innerHTML', 'N/A').trim()
  var info3 = querySelectorGet("a.classC span", 'innerHTML', 'N/A').trim()

  //For scraping different texts of the same kind (i.e: comments from users)
  var commentsTags = document.querySelectorAll('div.classComments');
  var comments =  Array.prototype.map.call(commentsTags, function(e) {
    return e.innerText;
  })

// Return all the rest of the information as a JSON string
  return {
    info1: info1,
    info2: info2,
    info3: info3,

    // There is no fixed number of comments & answers so we join them with a semicolon
    comments : comments.join(' ; ')
  };
}

casper.start('http://myurl.com/login', function() {
this.sendKeys('#username', 'username', {keepFocus: true});
this.sendKeys('#password', 'password', {keepFocus: true});
this.sendKeys('#password', casper.page.event.key.Enter, {keepFocus: true});

  // Logged In
  this.wait(3000,function(){

    //Verify connection by printing welcome page's title
    this.echo( 'Opened main site titled: ' + this.getTitle());
  });
});

casper.then( function() {

  //Quick summary
  this.echo('# of links : ' + limit);
  this.echo('scraping links ...')

  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

    // Building the urls to visit
    var link = root + end;

        // Visiting pages...
        casper.thenOpen(link).then(function() {
            // We pass the querySelectorGet method to use it within the webpage context
            var row = this.evaluate(scrapDetails, querySelectorGet);
            scrapedRows.push(row);

            // Stats display
            this.echo('Scraped row ' + scrapedRows.length + ' of ' + limit);
        });

    end++;
  }

});

casper.then(function() {
  fs.write('infos.json', JSON.stringify(scrapedRows), 'w')
});

casper.run( function() {
  casper.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point I probably have more questions than answers but let's try.

Is there a particular reason why you're using CasperJS and not Curl for example ? I can understand the need for CasperJS if you are going to scrape a site that uses Javascript for example. Or you want to take screenshots. Otherwise I would probably use Curl along with a scripting language like PHP or Python and take advantage of the built-in DOM parsing functions.
And you can of course use dedicated scraping tools like Scrapy. There are quite a few tools available.

Then the 'obvious' question: do you really need to have arrays *that large* ? What you are trying to achieve is not clear, I am assuming you will want to store the extracted links to a database or something. Isn't it possible to split the process in small batches ?

One thing that should help is to **allocate sufficient memory** by declaring a **fixed-size array** ie:
`var theArray = new Array(1000);`

Resizing the array constantly is bound to cause performance issues. Every time new items are added to the array, expensive memory allocation operations must take place in the background, and are repeated as the loop is being run.

Since you are not showing any code, so we cannot suggest meaningful improvements, just generalities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Anonymous! I didn't consider Curl as I only knew PhantomJS, CasperJS and SlimmerJS were the most popular languages for web scrapping. Based on your answer, I think Curl might do the trick so I'll definitively give it a shot. I used import.io for scraping but I can't afford their plans so I decided to self teach myself to CasperJS. I need to scrape hundreds of thousands web pages so at some point, I'll need large arrays to store the URLs. I didn't allocate memory so here again, I'll try this too and compare the results. I've updated my question with my code ;)